# Looking for examples of simple web-based form designers

Tags: asp.net, javascript, html, ajax, dom

I have a requirement to implement a "simple" web-based form designer that allows "simple" users to create their own web-based forms. I've come across these things in rich clients, such as Outlook and Acrobat, but my requirements are much simpler and must be web-based.

Pretty layout, custom validation, complex fields and types are simply not a factor. Ideally I would like to find something that is neat like this very SO question composer, in which I'm typing right now, plus the ability to drag a text input box or a checkbox right into the text. Output could be as crude as this:

> What is your name? [Fred Bloggs]
>   Do you have an internet? [x]

I'm using asp.net but the backend technology doesn't really matter as I fear this is all javascript! No need to consider old browsers. Any examples links would be helpful, as well as suggestions for existing open or commercial components. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Tried [Frevvo](http://www.frevvo.com/frevvo/web/static/home) ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty neat one based on jquery [Ajax Form Builder](http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/Ajax-Form-Builder-Project/)

Answer (score 0):

Try [FormThis](http://www.formthis.com).  It allows you to create an Online Web Form at no cost.  Drag & Drop designer, Unlimited Fields, Submit/Responses, Calculations, Validation, etc.  Can output to PDF if required.